# Mustache check if there are placeholders in a url

Tags: javascript, render, placeholder, mustache

I'm new to mustache:
In my company we are using mustache to render placeholders.
I have read the manual in https://mustache.github.io/ and some other tutorials but could not find nothing that helps me detect placeholders inside some url.

Example:
//workflow/v99/history/{{ espisodeId }}

EpisodeId is a Placeholder that a user as put in a URL stored in a database.

I need to be able to get this URL from the database and be able to detect if it as placeholders and where they are located in the url.
I can split the url by / ... but how to detect if it has placeholders with mustache?

Thanks for the help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` to check if there is a mustache in the url by `/{{.*?}}/` and `test` method.

```js
let url = 'workflow/v99/history/{{ espisodeId }}'

let hasMustache = (url) => {
  return /{{.*?}}/.test(url);
}

console.log(hasMustache(url));
```

Comment: I also found that Mustache has a very useful built in function called parse() that helps doing the same kind of thing i asked.